# How do I determine when Google maps is Speaking in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to modify my application to pause audio playback when Google maps is announcing a turn by turn direction.

I've added the following code (shown below) to my application. The audio focus listener is called when applications like Pandora Radio or Spotify request audio focus in order to play music but it's not called when Google maps announces a turn by turn direction. Is there another intent I should be listening for in order to detect this behavior?

```
 AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.requestAudioFocus(new AudioFocusRequest.Builder(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN)
            .setAudioAttributes(
                    new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                            .build()
            )
            .setAcceptsDelayedFocusGain(true)
            .setOnAudioFocusChangeListener(new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
                    // This is called by Pandora Radio and Spotify
                    Log.d("Focus change:", " Event is: " + focusChange);
                }
            }).build());
```

Comment: Have you checked with different `AudioAttributes`?

Comment: @MorrisonChang I have, but the listener still isn't called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need `AudioManager`'s `AudioPlaybackCallback` updates.

This only works on Android O and above.

To do this you have to access the audio manager -

```
 AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

And then add the listener like this -

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    audioManager.registerAudioPlaybackCallback(new AudioManager.AudioPlaybackCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaybackConfigChanged(List<AudioPlaybackConfiguration> configs) {
             super.onPlaybackConfigChanged(configs);
            // This will be called when navigation audio state on google maps changes
            Log.d("audio active", String.valueOf(audioManager.isMusicActive()));
        }
    }, handler);
}
```

The `List<AudioPlaybackConfiguration> configs` returned in the callback has a `AudioAttribute` object which contains a string describing the audio playing. For Google maps navigation the String constant value is `USAGE_ASSISTANCE_NAVIGATION_GUIDANCE` which you can compare to be sure that it is Google Maps announcing the navigation direction.

Programatically you can get it like this

```
// Loop through the configs to see the media's usage data
configs.get(0).getAudioAttributes().getUsage();
```

Answer (score 0):

For Android O, the missing navigation duck focus change notifications were only received after I explicitly set my player's AudioAttributes and content type to speech (as I am playing podcast mp3 files, didn't test with other content types):

```
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
AudioAttributes.Builder aab = new AudioAttributes.Builder();
aab.setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH);
aab.setUsage(USAGE_MEDIA);
player.setAudioAttributes(aab.build());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
        switch (focusChange) {
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
                if (mPlayOnAudioFocus && !isPlaying()) {
                    play();
                } else if (isPlaying()) {
                    setVolume(MEDIA_VOLUME_DEFAULT);
                }
                mPlayOnAudioFocus = false;
                break;
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
                setVolume(MEDIA_VOLUME_DUCK);
                break;
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
                if (isPlaying()) {
                    mPlayOnAudioFocus = true;
                    pause();
                }
                break;
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
                mAudioManager.abandonAudioFocus(this);
                mPlayOnAudioFocus = false;
                stop();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The following code snippet contains an implementation of this interface for an app that plays audio. And it handles ducking for transient audio focus loss. It also handles audio focus change due to the user pausing playback, vs another app (like the Google Assistant) causing transient audio focus loss

does your app temporarily need audio focus (with the option to duck), since it needs to play an audio notification, or a turn by turn spoken direction, or it needs to record audio from the user for a short period of time? This is

> AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK.

**Ducking vs pausing on transient audio focus loss**
You can choose to pause playback or temporarily reduce the volume of your audio playback in the OnAudioFocusChangeListener, depending on what UX your app needs to deliver. Android O supports auto ducking, where the system will reduce the volume of your app automatically without you having to write any extra code. In your OnAudioFocusChangeListener, just ignore the AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK event.

In Android N and earlier, you have to implement ducking yourself (as shown in the code snippet above).

for Detail visit :https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/audio-focus-3-cdc09da9c122

[AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK)
added in API level 8
public static final int AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK
Used to indicate a temporary request of audio focus, anticipated to last a short amount of time, and where it is acceptable for other audio applications to keep playing after having lowered their output level (also referred to as "ducking"). Examples of temporary changes are the playback of driving directions where playback of music in the background is acceptable.

Answer (score -2):

You should use "AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT", according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT):

**AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT**

*Used to indicate a temporary gain or request of audio focus, anticipated to last a short amount of time. Examples of temporary changes are the **playback of driving directions**, or an event notification.*

Comment: AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT is used to request audio focus. This doesn't change the behavior of the audio focus changed listener.

Comment: Yes it does, AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN is used to indicate a gain of audio focus but AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT also listen to request of audio focus "anticipated to last a short amount of time (like the playback of driving directions)", this actually works on my application, hope it helps!

Comment: Isn't an open source project, sorry, but this code is where I do the request to handle the audio focus
"audioManager.requestAudioFocus(focusChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 
                AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);"